# "the page elements" or "the page's elements"

Tags: phrases, adjectives, possessives

Many times I see constructions like

> the node's text , the node text
>
> the node's tag, the node tag
>
> the page elements, the page's elements
>
> the page footer (to mean the footer of page), the page header...

I know that they are different but it seems sometimes they can be used in place of each other. for example what is the difference of

- the page elements
- the elements of page
- the page's elements

I found it awkward to repeat *the page's elements* if I can't use "the page elements".

Are there times that we can use both an adjective and a possessive construction for something?

Comment: why not use pronouns to avoid repetition? - just a suggestion

Comment: @shin in an article they may appear in various parts.

Answer (score 1):

No, a noun adjunct (a noun modifying a noun) is **not** always interchangeable with possessive construction.

You cannot say that a 'mountain bike' is a bike owned by a mountain if you make it possessive (i.e., mountain's bike??)

'Node's tag' means that there is a node, and the tag (specified) is of that node.

'Node tag' means a tag used for a node (in general).

Comment: Maybe not the exact interchangeable, but I feel there are cases when "node's tag" and "node tag" are the same. or any other example you say.

Comment: please consider my other example in the updated question.

Comment: I found this explanation:  ". . .you use the possessive for a more generic meaning, and the compound to pick out some more idiomatic. . ."

source: [http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87591/a-noun-adjunct-the-possessive-case]

Comment: @Ahmad The node's tag can say anything... a "node tag" would probably say "node".

Comment: @Catija some of my examples may don't work. but how about others? for example page footer to mean the footer of the page.

Comment: Of course they are sometimes interchangeable... This answer doesn't say that they aren't, it simply says that they can't **always** be interchangeable.

Comment: @Catija yes, but my question is actually when and for which cases they could be interchangeable, how can I distinguish that.

Comment: @Ahmad It would likely  be pretty impossible for us to create a list of when it's always OK and when it's never OK...

Comment: @Catija I myself guess if I can say "The X of Y" and Y is generic then I may say "Y X", but when I mean "The X of the Y", I'd better say "Y's X". For example "the page footer" can be translated to "the footer of page" where page is generic or unspecific.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems to be related to whether X is a part of Y. In these cases, the node is made up of a text and tag, the page is made up of elements, the page has header and footer parts. In cases where Y contains X like this, then to specify what kind of X you mean you can say the Y X, which is the kind of X inside a Y.